# How to add a file to a document library from a list?

Tags: list, document-library

Here's the scenario I'm facing. I have a list of candidates to be recruited and a document library where I want to store the candidates' CVs.

What I want to do is when I create a new item in the list of candidates, there will be an option for me to upload the CVs straight to the document library; then a column in the list named CVs, will be automatically updated with the link to that exact document in the library.

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of uploading CV to different document library, you can attach it to list item.

- Click on **new item**
- In the ribbon, go to **EDIT** tab & click on **Attach File**, then you will get **Browse..** button for uploading. Upload the CV file & click **OK**.

[image]

---

**Other way:** Create lookup column in list on document library

- In your list, Go to **List Settings** > **Create column**
- Give Column Name(Your CV document Title)
- In type, select **Lookup**
- In *Get information from* > select your document library.
- In *in this column*  > Select column of document library you want to display in list (Title)
- Click **OK**

Now, Create new item in list with attached CV file from document library.

Comment: But when you view the item, the attachment column only shows an icon and not a link to open/edit the foles; or there's a way to do it?

Comment: Select the list Item & Go to "Ribbon > View Item" to view the attachment.

Comment: I tried your 2nd option, but I can't seem to **lookup** column **Name**. They only allow the predefined columns, namely **ID, Title, Created, Modified, Version, & Copy Source**. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Lookup is column type like Number & Single line of text. As you accepted this answer, hope you got solution now.